# How much resources are required to compile and run a java program?

Tags: java, swing

There is a java swing program with many variables and functions of scope class and method to capture data to generate an xml message. 
I started with approach, initialising all GUIs in a single method and encountered limitation of maximum method size of 64k.
Later, I selected approach of initialising a panel and its immediate children in a method to overcome it.
 Some, Observations about the program, as follows:

I)
a) Size : 6.67 MB (69,98,520 bytes)
b) kloc : 136k (135934 lines)

II) Class Scope :
a) JPanel : 1380
b) GridBagConstraints : 1380
c) JTextArea : 355
d) JTextField : 3601
e) JScrollPane : 355
f) JFormattedText : 1149
k) JSpinner : 1149
l) int : 1364
m) String Arrays : 1364
n) functions    : 3550 [1380 (GUI initilisors)+1791 (setters)]

III) Method Scope:
a) inner functions: 376
b) for loops: 752 
c) if branching : 2257
d) try...catch : 377
e) int : 376
f) JLabel : 4750
g) JPanel : 4750
h) JSpinner : 377
i) String : 752
and 
IV)
a) no method is exceeding in size 64kb 
b) sum of number of variables and methods less than 64k
c) Java Compiler throws:
 i) "system out of resources" exception or 
ii) "too many constants" exception

What are parameters are taken in to consideration while calculating the required resources to compile and run from the java program? and 
How much resources are required to compile and run the said java program?

Answer (score 1):

The method size is the amount of *bytecode* required. This may include fully qualified class names, so it may sometimes be larger than your *source* file.

The maximum method size is a **file format limitation** of the Java runtime.
It was expected that this is "large enough for any meaningful program" (unfortunately, sometimes generated code *can* be meaningful, but larger).

The solution is to **structure your program**. Use more methods.

Answer (score 0):

To see how much resources the application is using at runtime, there is a tool called jvisualvm in your JDK.

It will show just about everything you need to see.